# Issue with z-index in IE7 for tooltip

Tags: css, z-index, internet-explorer-7

I have a jQuery tooltip that works correctly in all other browsers(including IE8), but the popup is coming under the page content.

```
#datasearch2-tooltip .tipBody 
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 15px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px#000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #000;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

The z-index of 9999 should set the tooltip above all over content, as it does in other browsers. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Your HTML matters. Please add it to your question.

Comment: As a side note, border-radius and box-shadow won't work in IE7. And what z-index does `#datasearch2-tooltip` have, or the parent of that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the `position` rule:

```
#datasearch2-tooltip .tipBody 
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 15px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px#000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #000;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

`z-index` only affects elements that have position set (other than `position: static`)

Take a look at [this page](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) for more info on z-index

Comment: I set `position: relative;`, but the issue still persists.

Comment: @Matt have you added it to the other elements it'll be overlapping?